# DownloadFile via System.Net.WebClient doesn't works

Tags: vb.net

I can't download any file with following code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    DownloadFile("http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/videolan/vlc/2.0.3/vlc-2.0.3.tar.xz", "C:\TEST\vlc-2.0.3.tar.xz")
End Sub

Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _URL As String, ByVal _SaveAs As String)
        Dim _WebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
        _WebClient.DownloadFile(_URL, _SaveAs)
End Sub
```

Following errors will pop up: (translated from german to english):

From the Microsoft Error Pop-UP: 
[image]

==> A not treated exeption from type "System.Net.WebException" appeared in System.dll.

And at the debugger:
[image]

==> Exeption: Triggered: "An invalid argument has been specified" (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException) System.Net.Sockets.SocketException has been triggered. "An invalid argument has been specified"

FULL CODE:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form2
    Dim str_hd As String

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        For Each drive As System.IO.DriveInfo In My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives
            Dim dbl_capacity As Double
            Dim dbl_free As Double
            Dim dbl_used As Double

            If drive.IsReady Then
                dbl_capacity = drive.TotalSize / 1073741824
                dbl_free = drive.TotalFreeSpace / 1073741824
                dbl_used = dbl_capacity - dbl_free

                dbl_capacity = Fix(dbl_capacity * 1) / 1
                dbl_free = Fix(dbl_free * 10) / 10
                dbl_used = Fix(dbl_used * 10) / 10


                str_hd = str_hd & "Laufwerk " & drive.Name & "  -  " _
                        & drive.VolumeLabel & vbCrLf _
                        & "Benutzt: " & dbl_used & " GB" & " / " & dbl_capacity & " GB" & vbCrLf & "Frei: " _
                        & dbl_free & "GB" & vbCrLf & "-------------------------------" & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next

        txtbox_hd.Text = str_hd

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        DownloadFile("http://www.aerztekammer-hamburg.de/berufsrecht/Berufsordnung.pdf", "C:\TEST\Berufsordnung.pdf")
    End Sub



    Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _URL As String, ByVal _SaveAs As String)
            Dim _WebClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
            _WebClient.DownloadFile(_URL, _SaveAs)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the folder `C:\TEST` exist? Also, from the documentation:

> When using this method in a middle tier application, such as an ASP.NET page, you will receive an error if the account under which the application executes does not have permission to access the file.
>
> Wenn Sie diese Methode in einer Anwendung der Middle-Tear verwenden, z. B. einer ASP.NET-Seite, erhalten Sie eine Fehlermeldung, wenn das Konto, unter dem die Anwendung ausgeführt wird, nicht über die Berechtigung zum Zugriff auf die Datei verfügt.

Comment: Yes, the folder "C:\TEST" exists. And how can I set up an account for that? When you type the given url in your browser, the file would be downloaded without permission checks...

Comment: Are you creating an ASP.NET page? The above only creates an error if the Internet Information Service does not have write access to the folder.

Comment: Nop, I don't create any ASP.NET page. I only try to download that file from its ftp server. I will add the full code in 1min..

Comment: Ah, I see from the other exceptions in the list that an error occurred creating the WebProxy. Could it be you're trying to use a web proxy to download the file? Will the code work on a network where you don't need to use the proxy?

Comment: Thanks Thorsten... There was actually a proxy from our company... ;) It works now really fine :))